# Populate Angular Modal on ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is a seemingly simple task that I'm kinda struggling with.

I have a table of events coming from an ng-repeat. I want the user to be able to click on the event name and have it pop up a modal with the event details.

I currently have an `ng-click="eventDetails(objectId)"` linked to the title name. Then in my controller this is my code

```
app.controller('viewEventRequestsController', function($scope, EventFactory){

// this gets a list of events, one of the properties of the event is called objectId
        EventFactory.query(function(response){
            $scope.events = response.results;
        });

//this is the function that runs when I click, the event name.          
           $scope.eventDetails = function(objectId){
            $scope.modalOn = true;
             $scope.modal = EventFactory.get({ objectId: objectId });

             console.log($scope.modal)

        }

    });
```

This is part of my markup

```
<tr ng-repeat="items in events | filter:filter | orderBy:sort:reverse">
        <td>
            <a ng-click="eventDetails(objectId)">{{items.Name}}</a>
        </td>
```

My console.log($scope.modal); is returning the full array of objects not the single object I clicked on.

Yet in a different part of my app when I use `$scope.events = EventFactory.get({ objectId: $routeParams.objectId });` this works fine. The reason I can't do it this way is because I need the eventDetails to pop up in a modal not redirect to its own page. So I'm unable to use `$routeParams` this time.

Any ideas on how I can implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a typo in your post but... just in case your actual code is like that, you're passing an inexistent object into your eventDetails function here:

```
    <a ng-click="eventDetails(objectId)">
```

what you need to pass is

```
    <a ng-click="eventDetails(items.itemId /*or whatever the id field is */)">
```

because you're iterating the eventDetails array and assigning the value of each element to the **items** variable here:

```
    ng-repeat="items in events | filter:filter | orderBy:sort:reverse"
```

Like I said, not sure if typo or not, but the fact that you're getting all the Events as if you didn't pass any filter, it's behaving like calling get() without any filters.

**--- UPDATE ---**

Since you have your Events locally, you can get an individual event without having to resort to another server request.

Try this on your eventDetails() function:

```
    $scope.eventDetails = function(event){

       $scope.modalOn = true;
       var index = $scope.events.indexOf(event);
       if(index > -1){
         $scope.modal = $scope.events[index];
       }
    }
```

on your html just pass the full item as an argument to the function:

```
    <tr ng-repeat="items in events | filter:filter | orderBy:sort:reverse">
    <td>
        <a ng-click="eventDetails(items)">{{items.Name}}</a>
    </td>
```

Comment: Yup that was it! Can't believe I missed that. One thing I'm wondering though, if I already have the needed data in the table, is there a way I could refactor this code to not need to make another `GET` request?

Comment: Yep I've updated my answer to allow you to retrieve an event without making another request to the server